# Attaching additional hidden information to Woocommerce order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, orders

So I'm stuck with a problem in Woocommerce here.
I don't know if the subject of this question is the solution here, but let me explain what I want to achieve.

I've created this function that sums all the total prices of the products in a cart within a certain category into a subtotal. Based on that subtotal the user gets a message that says what amount in € users get:

```
## Category based sum ##
function cat_cart_sum($cat_id) {
    if ( ! is_page( 'winkelmand' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $cat_count = 0; 
    // Iterating through each cart item
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item)  
        if( has_term( $cat_id, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'])) {
            $regularprice = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
            $price = $regularprice * $cart_item['quantity'];
            $cat_count += $price;
        }
    if ($cat_count >= 40 && $cat_count <= 100) {
        wc_add_notice('U krijgt bij het afhalen €10 gratis vuurwerk!', 'notice');
        } elseif ($cat_count > 100 && $cat_count <= 200) {
            wc_add_notice('U krijgt bij het afhalen €25 gratis vuurwerk!', 'notice');
        } elseif ($cat_count > 200 && $cat_count <= 300) {
            wc_add_notice('U krijgt bij het afhalen €50 gratis vuurwerk!', 'notice');
        } elseif ($cat_count > 300 && $cat_count <= 400) {
            wc_add_notice('U krijgt bij het afhalen €75 gratis vuurwerk!', 'notice');
        } elseif ($cat_count >= 400) {
            wc_add_notice('U krijgt bij het afhalen €100 gratis vuurwerk!', 'notice');
        }
    return $cat_count;
}
```

The users now know how much they are getting. But only in their cart. I want to be able to call this amount from anywhere e-mail, invoice or whatever. 
I'm lost in this problem. Does anyone have a solution?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WC()->cart` object will not work with Orders and with Email notifications… So you cant use it once customer has checkout.

Also with `if ( ! is_page( 'winkelmand' ) )  return;` this code will only work on page `'winkelmand'`… For Order.

Below you will find your rearranged function with 3 arguments:

- `$cat_id` (the category ID)
- `$arg` (optional: The order ID or the WC_Order Object)
- `$is_email` (optional: (boolean) to be set to 'true' on email notifications only)

This function has 2 loops:

- The cart items loop that will work if `$arg` is not defined…
- The Order items loop that will work instead if `$arg` is defined (by the Order Id or the order object).

Here is the code of your function:

```
function cat_sum( $cat_id, $arg = null, $is_email = false ) {
    // Will work everywhere except on page 'winkelmand'
    if ( is_page( 'winkelmand' ) ) return;

    $total_count = 0;
    $type = gettype($arg);

    // 1. WC_Cart
    if( $type == 'NULL' && gettype(WC()->cart) == 'object' && ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ){
        // Iterating through each cart item
        foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item)
            if( has_term( $cat_id, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) )
                $total_count += $cart_item['data']->get_price() * $cart_item['quantity'];
        $is_order = false; // Not an order
    }
    // Order ID is set in $arg
    elseif( $type == 'integer' || $type == 'string' ){
        // get an instance of the WC_Order object
        $order = wc_get_order($arg);
        $is_order = true; // An order
    }
    // WC_Order Object is set in $arg
    elseif( $type == 'object' ){
        $order = $arg;
        $is_order = true; // An order
    }
    else return;

    // 2. WC_Order
    if( $is_order )
        foreach($order->get_items() as $item )
            if( has_term( $cat_id, 'product_cat', $item->get_product_id() ) )
                $total_count += $item->get_product()->get_price() * $item->get_quantity();

    // Display notice
    if ( $total_count >= 40 && $total_count <= 100 )
        $message = __( 'U krijgt bij het afhalen €10 gratis vuurwerk!' );
    elseif ( $total_count > 100 && $total_count <= 200 )
        $message = __( 'U krijgt bij het afhalen €25 gratis vuurwerk!' );
    elseif ( $total_count > 200 && $total_count <= 300 )
        $message = __( 'U krijgt bij het afhalen €50 gratis vuurwerk!' );
    elseif ( $total_count > 300 && $total_count <= 400 )
        $message = __( 'U krijgt bij het afhalen €75 gratis vuurwerk!' );
    elseif ( $total_count >= 400 )
        $message = __( 'U krijgt bij het afhalen €100 gratis vuurwerk!' );
    else return;

    if( ! $is_email ){
        wc_add_notice( $message, 'notice' );
        return $total_count;
    } else {
        return array(
            'total' => $total_count,
            'notice' => $message
        );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

**USAGE:**

1) When WC_Cart object is available (before customer has checkout). You will use it as you do *(for example with 'clothing' category)*:

```
$cat_count = cat_sum( 'clothing' );
echo '<p>'.$cat_count.'</p>';
```

2) When WC_Cart object is not available (after customer has checkout). you will need to set the Order ID or the WC_Order Object like in this example in Order received page (Thankyou):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'cat_count_in_thankyou', 10, 1 );
function cat_count_in_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    echo '<p>'.cat_sum( 'clothing', $order_id ).'</p>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**3) In Email notifications** *(the WC_Cart object is not available and Notices are not displayed)* and you will need to set the Order ID or the WC_Order Object. For this case, we use the third argument set to `true`. The function will return an array with the category count and the corresponding message (notice).

This example will work on email notifications:

```
// Display the total Cat in email notifications
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'add_cat_sum_to_emails', 9, 4 );
function add_cat_sum_to_emails( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    $cat_sum = cat_sum( 'clothing', $order, true );
    echo '<p>Total cat: '.$cat_sum['total'].'</p>';
}

// Display the notice in email notifications
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'add_custom_notice_to_emails', 4, 4 );
function add_custom_notice_to_emails( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    $cat_sum = cat_sum( 'clothing', $order, true );
    echo '<p style="border:solid 1px #333; padding:12px;"> '.$cat_sum['notice'].'</p>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Everything is tested and works.